# Custom View Animation

Tags: android, animation, view

In my **Android** application I have a custom View object which I am referencing in a layout like thus:

```
<view
    class="com.usmaan.game.MenuBall"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"/>
```

The class looks like this:

```
public class MenuBall extends View {

public MenuBall(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    canvas.drawCircle(getMeasuredWidth() * 0.5f, getMeasuredHeight() * 0.5f, getMeasuredHeight() * 0.5f, paint);
}
}
```

The ball/circle is being drawn perfectly fine on the screen.

What I wish to do however is to animate the ball so that it moves vertically and/or horizontally. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Did you take a look at the [animation guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)?
You can put that view inside a RelativeLayout and use property animations to move it around.

Comment: What you haven't mentioned is how you want the ball to move.  Do you want it onTouch, sensors, other?

Comment: @digiholic Hi digiholic. For the moment, I'm just interested in making the ball move without any user input. so for example, I want the ball to move from it's current location to location X and then back again.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can instantiate your view in an activity and animate it like any other view, you can see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html for more reference

Answer (score 1):

This sleep should be done in a thread so as not to lock the ui up, but will give you an idea of one way to do it.  There are a few ways to do it, really just depends on what you want it to do in relation to user/app events.

```
 float x= getMeasuredWidth() * 0.5f;
 float destinationX= getMeasuredWidth() * 0.8f;
 boolean isRunning=true;
 Paint paint = new Paint();
 paint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
super.onDraw(canvas);

 while (isRunning) {
            Thread.sleep(200); // Waits for .2 second (200 milliseconds)
            if(x<destinationX){
                x+=5;} 
            else {isRunning=false;}
            canvas.drawCircle(x,y, getMeasuredHeight() * 0.5f, paint);
            invalidate();
 }
}
```

Comment: Is that sleep to make the animation start slightly after it's instantiated so it gives the user a chance to view the page and THEN see the animation begin? Furthermore, how do I make sure it doesn't lock up the UI?

Comment: By saying you want the ball to move between locations really gives no information on what you are trying to accomplish.  The code above literally will move the ball between 2 locations.  The sleep redraws 5 times every second.  Have the loop running off of the main thread, that way the thread sleep isn't on the main.  IF you are trying to do the animation and then show a view, where isRunning is set to false you could then call a view or whatever, but IF you just want something as a animated splash or something, there are easier ways.